# How do you "select-all" in Apple Calendar (iCal)?

Tags: macos, calendar, shortcut, ical

I use my calendar like a scheduled to-do list.  I sometimes want to shift all today's events down by 15 minutes.  *Select All* is grayed out in the Edit menu, and it's tedious to click on every event while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

How do you select all events on a particular day?  If there isn't a way, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot use <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> in the "day" section. But, if you want to select specific events, hold down <kbd>Command</kbd> and click on the events you want to copy or do whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can't. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> only works in month view, and then it only works for the current month. The other reply is correct, holding <kbd>Cmd</kbd> is the only way to select multiple events.

Answer (score 0):

#### Coarse Solution Using macOS Calendar alone: Use "Select All" in Month View

1. Hide calendars you don't want to edit.
2. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> (Week View)
3. *Recommended:* Select one of the events you want to edit so the next step focuses on that time period.
4. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> (Month View)
5. *The Fussy Part:* Scroll to the time period that shows only the events you want to edit.
6. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (Select All)
7. *Optional step if you want to adjust event **time**:* <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> (Week View)
8. <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd> (<- this key may be unnecessary), <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> (shift event dates or times)

#### Accurate Solution Using Apple Shortcuts

1. Create a new Shortcut
2. **Add Action: "Find Calendar Events"** and adjust settings
3. *Optional:* Add the following Actions if you want to be safe:

   - "Show Result"
   - "Stop This Shortcut"
4. **Add Action: "Adjust Date"** and adjust settings